# Spritekit Adding Particles

Tags: ios, swift3, sprite-kit, particles

I want to make my spaceship have a particle trail that follows it. How would I do this?

Here's my code for my spaceship:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    spaceS.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
    spaceS.setScale(0.05)
    spaceS.zPosition = 1

    addChild(spaceS)

}
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            spaceS.position = CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y)
        }


}
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
               for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            spaceS.position = CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y)
        }


}
```

EDIT 1: A fire particle trail to be more exact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create a `SpriteKit Particle File` by pressing ***command + n*** on keyboard and from the template under `iOS` -> `Resources` -> choose `SpriteKit Particle File` click `Next` and choose `particle template` to `fire` press next and give a name to `SpriteKit Particle File` this will create a **`yourFileName.sks`** file to your project.

Use the below code:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    spaceS = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
    spaceS.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
    spaceS.setScale(0.50)
    spaceS.zPosition = 1

    addChild(spaceS)

    let emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "MyParticle") //MyParticle is the name of the sks file.
    emitter?.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -spaceS.size.height)
    emitter?.zPosition = 1
    spaceS.addChild(emitter!) //Now the emitter is the child of your Spaceship.      
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: If the sprite is too small the fire doesn't appear, and it's also appearing in the middle of the sprite

Comment: I'll explain my last comment better. If the particle is set to a smaller scale, it appears in the middle of the sprite (It doesn't disappear)

Comment: Maybe your sprite is way smaller.Try down size your particle. if my answer helped to solve the problem you should accept the answer or upvote.

Comment: It's not too small, it's just directly in the middle of  the sprite

Comment: I'm not sure how you setting your sprite.Add some number to emitter y-position this way you can move the emitter downwards.

Comment: Is there a way I could add the particle to the scene and not as a child

Comment: addchild(emitter!)